# CSS rendering different in IE8 , as to do with float: right, and overflow hidden

Tags: css, css-float

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.subheader
{
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header
{
    width:200px; 
    height:20px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    border: 1px solid red;
}
span
{
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
    <div class="subheader">
        <span>Hellow asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfa<span>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to get the same behaviour in IE8 than IE9

the result in IE9 is: Hellow asdfasdfa
while in IE8 is: asdfasdfasdf (i cannot see the hellow at the begining)

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: displays the same in ie8 and ie9 for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add 
`max-width: 100%;` to `.subheader` section

Answer (score 0):

Your `.subheader` is floated right. This means that the subheader div will be aligned to the right of the outer header div. If you switch the `.subheader` to float left you get the effect you're looking for.

Also, `text-overflow: ellipsis;` is CSS3 so IE8 won't do it naturally.

```
.subheader
{
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```